# Recovering the relative path option

Tags: paths, rm

Managed to delete the relative path option in linux by typing in `rm .*`,    now I can't change or add files to any directory.   How can these be recovered?   Running a `ls -a` and the standard `.` and `..` directories are missing.   If I try to add them with `mkdir` it says they already exist

Comment: `rm` (without `-r`) doesn't delete directories ... What says `pwd`? and `ls -ald $(pwd)`?

Comment: $ls -ald $(pwd)
drwxrwsr-x 3  4096 Aug  9 15:48 /var/www/html/tools/v
$ ls -ald 
drwxrwsr-x 3  4096 Aug  9 15:48 .

I restarted the shell and the relative paths seemed to be ok, but trying to vim any files I get E297: Write error in swap file

Comment: @Nathan Please [edit] the question to add details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried restarting your shell? The folder is likely not deleted.

`rm .*` wouldn't be able to delete the current path because it doesn't specify the recursive `-r` flag.

Comment: I restarted the shell and the relative paths seemed to be ok, but trying to vim any files I get E297: Write error in swap file.   Doesn't seem to be a disk space issue as I was able to create several files before running the rm .* command

Comment: Did you try `df -h` to verify you have disk space?